# TextInputLayout shared element transition issue

Tags: android, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

Here we go: two Activities with a shared element transition (Button). The second `Activity` has a `TextInputLayout` with a hint:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:focusable="true"
              android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GO"
            android:transitionName="test"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                   android:hint="WTF?!">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The enter transition of the second `Activity` is delayed for clarifying the problem: The hint of the `TextInputLayout` ignores the transition animation and displayed immediately after the transition is started. At the end of the animation you can see the correctly animated EditText background (horizontal line) below the hint. Is this a bug or am I missing something? Here is the second `Activity`:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static void launch(Activity activity, View sharedElement) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SecondActivity.class);

        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, sharedElement, "test");
        activity.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Slide().setDuration(5000));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: This bug can be "fixed" by adding a background the the second Activity's layout.**

[image: without background][image: with background]

Comment: Which is your shared element? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: The shared element is the button, as you can see from the example code. The expectation is, that the hint of the TextInputLayout is properly animated as a part of the Activity transition, like the rest of the view (look at the proper transition of the EditText's background in the video).

Comment: Please, clarify your question. Your animated GIF looks nice, we've got it. It's pretty cool animation. But I can't understand, what's the problem? where is it? What I see if blue line moves up. That's all. And then a short blink -- line appears under input field. Is it expected? Is it not expected? Wtf?

Comment: The hint of the TextInputLayout is not animated and shows up immediately after transition to the second Activity is started. The blinking line is the background of the EditText appears at the end of the Activity transition. The blue line is a status bar of the second Activity while it is animated in. Nothing cool or special here just the code shown above.

Answer (score 16):

for API 21+

```
android:transitionGroup="true"
```

Add this line in `TextInputLayout`. It would fix it. Or if you have a few `TextInputLayout` then add that line to their container.

Answer (score 0):

I think its bug of `TextInputLayout`. I removed it and I gave the hint to `TextInputEditText` and it worked as you expected.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GO"
        android:transitionName="test" />


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="WTF?!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug. I submitted a [new issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69349485).

You can avoid this by defining an `android:background` for the second activity.